# Remove backup files that are over a year and anything but the end of the month except for the current month

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a powershell script that I am writing where I need to keep daily backups for the current month, end of the month backups for the year, and remove anything other than that.

```
$ThisYear = (Get-Date).year
$DailyLogs = (Get-Date).month

#Clean-Up Old Backup Files
Get-ChildItem 'D:\' | ForEach-Object {
    if ( $_.LastWriteTime.Year -gt $ThisYear) {
        Remove-Item
    }
    Elsif ( $_.LastWriteTime.Month -gt $ThisMonth -and $_.LastWriteTime.Date -ne ) {
        Remove-Item
    }
```

So far this should remove any backup files that are not from the current year. The piece I am trying to solve is how to delete the daily backups except for the backup files for the end of each month after the current month.  I am stuck about how to get the -ne to the last day of any given month part.

Edit:

```
#Clean-Up Old Backup Files
Get-ChildItem 'D:\Server Backup\' | ForEach-Object {
    if ( $_.LastWriteTime.Year -gt $ThisYear) {
        Remove-Item
    }
    Elsif ( $_.LastWriteTime.Month -gt $ThisMonth -and $_.LastWriteTime.Date -ne [System.DateTime]::DaysInMonth($_.LastWriteTime.Year, $($_.LastWriteTime.Month))) {
        Remove-Item
    }
}
```

Based on Lee's comment here is my idea.

Alternative with 30 day rolling and Beginning of the month:

```
$RollingYear = (Get-Date).AddDays(-365)
$Rolling30Days = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)

    if ( $_.LastWriteTime.AddDays(-365) -lt $RollingYear) {
        Remove-Item
    }
    Elseif ( $_.LastWriteTime.AddDays(-30) -lt $Rolling30Days -and $_.LastWriteTime.Date -ne (Get-Date -Year $_.LastWriteTime.Year, -Month $_.LastWriteTime.Month -Day 1)) {
        Remove-Item
    }
```

Comment: this will give you the last day of any given month >> `[datetime]::DaysInMonth($YearNumber, $MonthNumber)` << [*grin*]

Comment: Lee does the edit look right?

Comment: If anyone has any ideas around a rolling 30days code keeping the beginning of each month that would also work.

Comment: There are also the following ways. `$_.LastWriteTime.AddDays(1).Day -ne 1`.

Comment: @Shenanigator - that looks good! [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
param($Path)

$Now = (get-date)
$ThisYear = $Now.AddYears(-1).Year

#Clean-Up Old Backup Files
Get-ChildItem $path | ForEach-Object {
    if ( $_.LastWriteTime.Year -lt $ThisYear) 
    {
        write-output "-- would have deleted $($_.fullname) $($_.LastWriteTime.DateTime)"
    }
    Elseif ($_.LastWriteTime.Day -ne [System.DateTime]::DaysInMonth($_.LastWriteTime.Year, $($_.LastWriteTime.Month)))
    {
      write-output "would have deleted $($_.fullname) $($_.LastWriteTime.DateTime)"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Output "saved $($_.FullName) $($_.LastWriteTime.DateTime)"
    }

}
```

I assumed you wanted to keep 12 months from the day of the script run.

I used this to test your script out:

```
for ($i = 1; $i -lt 500; $i++)
{ 
    new-item "$i.txt"
    (Get-ChildItem "$i.txt").lastwritetime = (get-date).AddDays(-$i)
}
```

I commented out the first two write-outputs and here is my result:

```
saved C:\temp\temp\103.txt Friday, November 30, 2018 9:38:00 PM
saved C:\temp\temp\13.txt Thursday, February 28, 2019 9:37:59 PM
saved C:\temp\temp\133.txt Wednesday, October 31, 2018 9:38:00 PM
saved C:\temp\temp\164.txt Sunday, September 30, 2018 9:38:00 PM
saved C:\temp\temp\194.txt Friday, August 31, 2018 9:38:00 PM
saved C:\temp\temp\225.txt Tuesday, July 31, 2018 9:38:00 PM
saved C:\temp\temp\256.txt Saturday, June 30, 2018 9:38:00 PM
saved C:\temp\temp\286.txt Thursday, May 31, 2018 9:38:00 PM
saved C:\temp\temp\317.txt Monday, April 30, 2018 9:38:01 PM
saved C:\temp\temp\347.txt Saturday, March 31, 2018 9:38:01 PM
saved C:\temp\temp\378.txt Wednesday, February 28, 2018 9:38:01 PM
saved C:\temp\temp\406.txt Wednesday, January 31, 2018 9:38:01 PM
saved C:\temp\temp\41.txt Thursday, January 31, 2019 9:37:59 PM
saved C:\temp\temp\72.txt Monday, December 31, 2018 9:37:59 PM
```